# convert int to double for `*` operations with std::complex<double>

Tags: c++, c++11, physics

I'm a physicist trying to minimise typing out type conversions and casts in the code file intended for calculations (the equations and functions). The calculations usually involve complex numbers. So I extended the `complex<double>` type as `cd` for compactness and adding a few helping methods.

```
class cd: public complex<double> { ... }
```

The reason for extending rather than just using `typedef` is so that the physics symbol (`string`) and physical units (`string`) can be stored with the physical variable.

Now if in the calculations I have instances like

```
int i = 2;
cd z(1,2);
cout << i*z;
```

This gives an error as there is no operator that multiplies an `int` and `cd`. (tbh I thought c++ would automatically implicitly convert the `int` to a `double` and use the relevant operator.) Upon defining such an operator manually as such

```
cd operator*(const int& i, const cd& z)
{
  return cd(i*z.real(),i*z.imag());
}
```

c++ then warns about ambiguity of type-conversion for parts like

```
double x = 30;
x*z;
```

In the following `x` is a double and `I` is a `cd`.

```
 error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘const cd’)
   return pow(eps1/e0*kz2,2)-pow(eps2/e0*kz1*tanh(dist*1e-10*kz1/( x *I)),2);
                                                                  ~~~^~
In file included from libs/calc/include/calculation.h:12:0,
                 from scripts/dist_dependence.cpp:2:
libs/calc/include/complex_double.h:49:4: note: candidate: cd operator*(const int&, const cd&)
 cd operator*(const int& x, const cd& z)
```

Since the manual operator definition (above) can also be used for a `double` with `cd` - which is already defined in the standard library.

Now the above problem can be resolved by defining instead

```
cd operator*(const double& x, const cd& z)
{
  return cd(x*z.real(),x*z.imag());
}
```

However this prevents the following:

In addition to this, I would also like a conversion from `cd` to `double` so that complex numbers can be passed (without the need for explicitly converting) to functions that take real (`double` type) arguments. (convert `cd` to `double` if the imaginary part is zero, otherwise throw an error or something).
The problem is that when I define (in addition to the `double`-`cd` operator`*`:

```
operator double() {
    if (imag()==0.0) return real();
    throw "trying to cast a cd with non-zero imaginary part to double";
  }
```

inside the `cd` class.

It spits the following:

```
 warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
```

Only the `operator*` has been given here for example, but I'd like to do this for other math binary operations too.

Comment: Can you please include the errors/a [mre]?  You need to define a `double` version of your `operator *` if you want `double x = 30;
x*z;` to work.

Comment: This is a perfect scenario for *template*s usage

Comment: @NathanOliver I have already tried that, but it conflicts with another requirement (please see updated question). 
@BiagioFesta How would I go on about using templates? Do I somehow make the complex class use two specialisations? (`int` and `double`) ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what advantage your class would have over simply doing `typedef std::complex<double> cd;`. Also, an implicit conversion from complex to real is likely to introduce bugs and make your code less clear. If one sees `z.real()` as an argument to a function, then it's obvious that you are passing the real part of a complex number to the function. If you just pass `z`, then it gives the misleading impression that the function accepts a complex argument.

Comment: Using `typedef std::complex<double> cd;` (or `using cd = std::complex<double>;`, which is the same thing) instead of `class cd` could fix some of the errors.

Comment: @jjramsey The conversion from `complex` to `real` can have a `throw` if the imaginary part is not zero

Comment: `class cd: public complex<double>`. Probably not that great an idea. A non-member function should always be preferred over a member, and once you have eliminated all your cd members, there's nothing left in it. So just typedef your complex<double>.

Comment: Problem is `So I extended the complex<double>` you shouldn't do it. There is no need for it

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad "The conversion from complex to real can have a throw if the imaginary part is not zero." And if you don't have a conversion at all, then you can catch a misuse of a complex number at compile time, which is much better than leaving the error to be caught at runtime.

Comment: @jjramsey okay that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a minimal example that I believe demonstrates your problems. Hopefully it also illustrates to the commenters what you're trying to accomplish.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <string>

class cd: public std::complex<double> {
  public:
    cd(double re, double im):std::complex<double>(re,im),name("var1"){}
    operator double(){
      if (imag()==0.0) return real();
      throw "trying to cast a cd with non-zero imaginary part to double";
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const cd& z){
      os << z.name << "=(" << z.real() << "," << z.imag() << ")";
      return os;
    }

  private:
    std::string name;

};

cd operator*(const int& i, const cd& z){
  return cd(i*z.real(),i*z.imag());
}

cd operator*(const double& x, const cd& z){
  return cd(x*z.real(),x*z.imag());
}

void foo(double x){
  std::cout << "foo " << x << std::endl;
}


int main(){

  int i=2;
  cd z(1,2);
  std::cout << i*z << std::endl;

  double x=30;
  std::cout << x*z << std::endl;

  cd zz(3,0);

  foo(x*zz);

  std::cout << z*zz << std::endl;
}
```

which gives the following output from `g++` (version 7.4.0)

```
test_complex_double.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test_complex_double.cc:48:18: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
   std::cout << z*zz << std::endl;
                  ^~
In file included from test_complex_double.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:386:5: note: candidate 1: std::complex<_Tp> std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = double]
     operator*(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
test_complex_double.cc:22:4: note: candidate 2: cd operator*(const int&, const cd&)
 cd operator*(const int& i, const cd& z){
    ^~~~~~~~
test_complex_double.cc:48:18: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
   std::cout << z*zz << std::endl;
                  ^~
In file included from test_complex_double.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:386:5: note: candidate 1: std::complex<_Tp> std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = double]
     operator*(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
test_complex_double.cc:26:4: note: candidate 2: cd operator*(const double&, const cd&)
 cd operator*(const double& x, const cd& z){
    ^~~~~~~~
```

This is just a warning, and this example still compiles.

I think the solution is that you want your class to be a *container* for a `std::complex<double>`, not inherit from it. I'm assuming you want to inherit so that you don't have to implement wrapper functions around everything that `std::complex<double>` implements, but the container approach makes more sense in my opinion, and also resolves this specific problem.

Here's a working example that shows the container alternative:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <string>

class cd {
  public:
    cd(double re, double im):val(re,im),name("var1"){}
    cd(const std::complex<double>& v):val(v),name("var1"){}
    operator double(){
      if (val.imag()==0.0) return val.real();
      throw "trying to cast a cd with non-zero imaginary part to double";
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const cd& z){
      os << z.name << "=(" << z.real() << "," << z.imag() << ")";
      return os;
    }
    double real() const{return val.real();}
    double imag() const{return val.imag();}

    cd operator*(const cd& other)const{return val*other.val;}

  private:
    std::complex<double> val;
    std::string name;

};

cd operator*(const int& i, const cd& z){
  return cd(i*z.real(),i*z.imag());
}

cd operator*(const double& x, const cd& z){
  return cd(x*z.real(),x*z.imag());
}

void foo(double x){
  std::cout << "foo " << x << std::endl;
}


int main(){

  int i=2;
  cd z(1,2);
  std::cout << i*z << std::endl;

  double x=30;
  std::cout << x*z << std::endl;

  cd zz(3,0);
  foo(x*zz);

  std::cout << z*zz << std::endl;

}
```

This compiles without warnings and running the program produces the output:

```
var1=(2,4)
var1=(30,60)
foo 90
var1=(3,6)
```

Comment: Yes!, this does it. Although now I will have to define the various operators for my class, and the functions like sinh, sin, tan, etc from the complex class - so calling a sin(cd x) will actually call sin(complex<double> x), etc

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

> So I extended the `complex<double>` type as `cd`

This is common mistake made by beginners assuming that inheritance is answer for all problems, where in fact it is a source of many problems.

Just define a working type without inheritance and everything will work out of the box:

```cpp
using cd = std::complex<double>;
constexpr cd i{0 , 1};

int main (int , char **)
{
    cd x{ 1, 3};

    std::cout << x << '\n';
    std::cout << x*i << '\n';

    std::cout << x*i + 3.2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/OfOfonJFrTInR0ib

Disclaimer: `cd` is not best name for this symbol. Think about somethig more descriptive

Comment: (`std::cout << r* (some int) << '\n';` still doesn't work without the operator definition in your wandbox.org example)

Anyway, if I simply use a `typedef` (no inheritance), is there a good way to store/associate a symbol string and a units string with the complex variable?

Comment: this is done on purpose to prevent unwanted conversions (this may lead to data loss). Just do `r * cd(someInt)` or `r * (double)someInt` to force conversion.

Comment: Or you can define extra operator: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ywEJXTN87AiBDbNe but I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @MarekR I think `r * static_cast<cd::value_type>(someInt)` would offer more flexibility in case `cd` were redefined as, say, `std::complex<other_scalar_type>`.

Comment: @jjramsey I agree